# Manually setup node module

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I am unable to use below command because of proxy constraints in my organization. I tried all the possibilities, but no luck.

npm install bower -g

Then i tried the same command at some other location/machine where there is no proxy constraints and after installing the node module, i moved node module (bower) to my machine. I placed it at the global location i.e. %appdata%/npm/bower

Now if i try bower --version command at the terminal, it says that - 'bower' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

is there anything which i am missing here ? Please help me to find out the reason for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Two things, which i did and it's working now.

1. Moved the node modules into "node_modules" folder i.e. %appdata%/npm/node_modules/bower
2. Also moved both the files i.e. bower & bower.cmd into npm directory. Like
   %appdata%/npm/bower & %appdata%/npm/bower.cmd

After these changes, we can use node modules within proxy constraints environment also. Hope it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

you have to move the **bower** folder from **node_modules** and also the **bower.cmd** file.

you could also setup npm proxy...you can do it like this

For HTTP:
`npm config set proxy http://proxy_
host:port`

For HTTPS:
`npm config set https-proxy http://
proxy.company.com:8080`

and if you need to specify username and password you can do it like this

`http://username:password@
proxy.company.com:8080`